# Infinispan 12: CLI with self-signed certs

Tags: ssl, command-line-interface, tls1.2, infinispan, truststore

I setup infinispan 12 with self-signed certs and SSL/TLS configuration.  I have default on port 11222 and hotrod on 11322.

The application starts up with no problem and connect to 11322 with no problem.

I start up `cli.bat` and pass the truststore and password on command line.  I try to connect by doing a `connect https://DN:11222` and it gives a `Received fatal alert: handshake_failure` error.

The DN is the same DN name used for resolution in the application for hotrod which worked with no problem on port 11322.  Using the same DN on the cli.bat CLI command prompt line fails on port 11222.  The only way I can get this working for `cli.bat` is I have to add a SAN to my truststore and the problem is resolved.

Why do I need a SAN for `cli.bat` to work on SSL/TLS connection?

Comment: Are you running your cli and server from a Windows machine?

Comment: Yes, I'm on a Windows machine.  Does that have a connection?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using

```
cli.bat -t truststore.pfx -s secret -c https://DN:11222
```

Would it be possible for you to share the server configuration ?
I'm afraid I do not know what you mean by SAN (I assume it is not a storage area network).

Comment: Yes, I am using that command.  The SAN is Subject Alternative Name, part of keystore/truststore.